# multidimensional array in C++ hang

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, eclipse-cdt

I wanna to declare an array:
    int a[256][256][256]
And the program hang. (I already comment out all other codes...)
When I try int a[256][256], it runs okay.

I am using MingW C++ compiler, Eclipse CDT.

My code is:
    int main(){
        int a[256][256][256];
        return 0;
    }

Any comment is welcomed.

Comment: What do you mean by "comment out all other codes"? Do you mean that a program consisting of a single line, `int a[256][256][256]`, and an empty main method `int main() {}`, hangs?

Comment: 256*256*256 is 16 million elements; your array is 64 megabytes on a 32-bit system. Not unreasonable for modern systems, but if you're allocating on the stack (inside a function), it's probably bigger than your compiler and OS are expecting.

Comment: Oh, also, are you declaring a global variable, or is it local to some function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This might happen if your array is local to a function.  In that case, you'd need a stack size sufficient to hold 2^24 ints (2^26 bytes, or 64 MB).

If you make the array a global, it should work.  I'm not sure how to modify the stack size in Windows; in Linux you'd use "ulimit -s 10000" (units are KB).

If you have a good reason not to use a global (concurrency or recursion), you can use malloc/free.  The important thing is to either increase your stack (not a good idea if you're using threads), or get the data on the heap (malloc/free) or the static data segment (global).

Ideally you'd get program termination (core dump) and not a hang.  I do in cygwin.

Comment: +1, beat me to it!  Using malloc or new[] to allocate the memory from the heap would also fix the problem, if that's indeed the problem.

Comment: Attempt to eat 64MB from stack is most likely a problem, indeed, +1.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have 16MB of free continuous memory? Kind of hard to imagine but possible...

Comment: @bkritzer: 64MB; ints are 4 bytes. 8-)

Comment: Whoops, wasn't paying attention to the "int" part.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this

```
#include <malloc.h>
int main()
{
    int *a;
    a = (int*)malloc(256*256*256*sizeof(int)); // allocate array space in heap
    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, you get something like this:

[alt text http://bweaver.net/files/stackoverflow1.jpg](http://bweaver.net/files/stackoverflow1.jpg)

Because, as others have pointed out, in your code you're allocating the array on the stack, and blowing it up.

Allocating the array via malloc or its friends is the way to go. (Creating it globally works too, if you must go that route.)